# How to Store Multi-Step Form State in Redux Toolkit in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm building a project with React.js and Redux Toolkit, and I need to implement a multi-step form with the following components: Header, Stepper, Form, Summary, and Footer. Here's a screenshot of the layout I need to create:

[image]

The form will have multiple steps, and the user will need to fill out different fields on each step. I want to store the user's local state in the store when the user clicks on the "Next" button to go to the next step. How can I store the component's local state to the global state of the app using Redux Toolkit? Because the state and fields of the form will change at each step.

Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on how to structure my Redux store to accommodate the dynamic nature of the form, where the fields and validations will change based on the current step. I also need to update the summary component with the user's entered data as they progress through the form.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Asking for advice and opinions is against this forum's rules, instead you should post answerable questions that someone can fix your problem. What in here is the question? "*I'm just not sure how to integrate Redux Toolkit and store the local form state in the global store*" - use [useDispatch](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#use-redux-state-and-actions-in-react-components) hook.

Comment: Hello @Aleksandar, thanks for pointing out my mistake. The question is how can I send the user's local state to the globals store when the form is a different component and the summary is different?

Comment: I don't know how to send the component's local state to the global. The fields in the form will change at each step. The summary card component only displays the information stored in the store.

Comment: Currently, I can only change the current step of the Multi-step form by dispatching a function.

Comment: You need to know [lift state up](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#a-single-source-of-truth-for-each-state) concept. You should store the state in the parent component which includes the `Form` and `Summary` components.  You can create a state slice for each step.

Comment: Hello @LinDu, by lifting the state up, would it make unusual summary component rerenders?